# C# InstaSharper argument delivery

Tags: c#, .net, arguments

I have following code, but **I am not common with interfaces**. I never worked with <> in c# before.

```
IResult<InstaUser> userSearch = await api.SearchHashtag()
```

**Image:** [--This are the arguments information (image)--](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1xoW7.png).
.

**My problem:** I don't know what to fill in. First argument is a string (no problem), but then I don't know what to fill in, and how to fill it in.

**How would an example of this filled out look like?**

(InstaSharper doesn't provide egnough information for me how to fill this out)

**Thank you for your time!**

-------InstaSharpe.cs

```
/// <summary>
    ///     Searches for specific hashtag by search query.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="query">Search query</param>
    /// <param name="excludeList">Array of numerical hashtag IDs (ie "17841562498105353") to exclude from the response, allowing you to skip tags from a previous call to get more results</param>
    /// <param name="rankToken">The rank token from the previous page's response</param>
    /// <returns>List of hashtags</returns>
    Task<IResult<InstaHashtagSearch>> SearchHashtag(string query, IEnumerable<long> excludeList = null, string rankToken = null);
```

Comment: The other two arguments are optional. Just pass in the string

Comment: @tkausl But how would I fill them out?

Comment: @tkausl They are not optional. If I only fill out the string it is still marked as red

Comment: Probably because your variable `usersSearch` has the wrong type.

Comment: @tkausl No, this should be ok. First argument can be a string and third argument can be null, but the second argument does not work. I added the summary of this.

Comment: Second argument defaults to `null` too. If it doesn't work with only the string, add your compiler error message to the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the error myself

ProblemCode:

```
IResult<InstaUser> userSearch = await api.SearchHashtag("string")
```

GoodCode:

```
IResult<InstaHashtagSearch> userSearch = await api.SearchHashtag("string");
```

Attention to the <>

Thank you all for your time